# Having only websphere 7 admin console access, how can I get a JAX-WS URL

Tags: websphere

I am trying to determine the URL that a webservice is deployed to. The only source of information I have is the Admin Console.

Darryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WebSphere provided web service engine, it should be visible in admin console via:

```
Service providers > YourService> View WSDL
```

In WSDL you will have it in:

```
<soap:address location="ServiceURL" />
```

If URL in location is incorrect, you can build it based on:

- ServiceName - to get from WSDL `<service name="YourService" >` and
- context-root of your app - to get from `Enterprise Applications > YourEAR > Context Root For Web Modules`

It will be in the form: `http://host:port/context-root/serviceName`